# How to see Junit report in Jenkins

Tags: junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Hudson Post Build task in Jenkins. Now what to do to see junit report?

I tried setting up the source path to publish JUnit reports under test report XML tag. But i am not able to see the XML.

Comment: your build has junit repo and you wnat to pulish it? the you have to install "JUNIT plugin" the  post build action you get "Post Junit Report " task.

Comment: also you share the actual location of file and what you have mentioned in plugin.. mention your workspace path also.. so we can help you better

Comment: I've fixed the grammar and removed the 'TIA' line.

Comment: If you use maven and maven job in eclipse, the whole thing is out of the box.

Comment: @Gabor: No i am not using maven. All i need is- I have junit code, I want to see junit result on Jenkins.i have setup all plugins in Jenkins. I need what should i do to see my test result when build gets completed? I have setup path under publish junit report.

Comment: Any body having idea? Would be great help..